# Expected string or Byte like object Error

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, data-analysis

```
 from nltk import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
 text = data.loc[:, "text"]
 tokenizer = word_tokenize((text))
 print(tokenizer)
```

I am trying to perform a word tokenizer on a specific column on a dataset, and I have sliced out the column and passing it into the word_tokenizer object but when I try to print the words I get "Expected string or Byte like object Error".

Comment: the error is telling you what is wrong you are passing a Series not a string or byte like object try list comprehension or something similar: `tokenizer = [word_tokenize(text[i]) for i in range(len(text))]`

Comment: Just tried that. It's giving the same error, for the code above.

Comment: Then your data is probably mixed dtypes and not all strings set them as strings then try again: `data['text'] = data['text'].astype(str)`

Comment: I tried it but when I checked for type(text), it still says series.

Comment: correct because `type(text)` is a series...I will post an answer and try to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's assume this `dataframe`

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'text':['some thing', 'word', 'some more text']})
```

then when you run your script you should get an error because you are passing a series and not a string...

```
text = data.loc[:, "text"]
tokenizer = word_tokenize(text)
print(tokenizer)
```

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

word_tokenize will accept strings that's why `word_tokenize('some text')` will work. so you need to iterate through your series:

```
text = data.loc[:, "text"]
tokenizer = [word_tokenize(text[i]) for i in range(len(text))]
print(tokenizer)

[['some', 'thing'], ['word'], ['some', 'more', 'text']]
```

if you still get a type error then, most likely, not every value in `data['text']` is a string. Let's assume this dataframe now:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'text':['some thing', 'word', 'some more text', 1]})
```

performing the list comprehension on this dataframe will not work because you are trying to pass an `int` in `word_tokenize`

however if you change everything to a string it should work:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'text':['some thing', 'word', 'some more text', 1]})
data['text'] = data['text'].astype(str)

text = data.loc[:, "text"]
tokenizer = [word_tokenize(text[i]) for i in range(len(text))]
print(tokenizer)

[['some', 'thing'], ['word'], ['some', 'more', 'text'], ['1']]
```

you check your types by `print([type(text[i]) for i in range(len(text))])`

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean now. Thanks for the clarification this worked!